# Split string using regex expression

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, split

I need to split a dynamic string. The string may look like the one below having Code, Name and EffectDate. or it may have only (Code and Name) or (Code and EffectDate) or (Name and EffectDate). You got the point right.

```
{"Code":{"value":"1"},"Name":{"value":"Entity1"},"EffectDate":{"value":"23/11/2016"}}
```

to

```
...
this.data[0].key ='Code'; \\something like this (desired result) 
this.data[0].value = '1';
this.data[1].key = 'Name';
this.data[1].value = 'Entity1';
this.data[2].key = 'EffectDate'; 
this.data[2].value = '23/11/2016';
```

What i did in my code :

```
...
filters:string;
data:string[];
...
this.data = this.filters.split("\b(?:(?!value)\w)+[a-zA-Z0-9/]\b");
console.log(this.data);
```

I used this pattern **\b(?:(?!value)\w)+[a-zA-Z0-9/]\b** but still couldn't get the desired result. The this.filter always returns only one array with the same string. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

**Update #1:**

I'm using PrimeNg extension for datatable and i get event as a parameter. In that, event.filters returns me a list of filter objects. I cannot send the object to the service, it needs to be in the format to work with the service.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to parse a JSON object manually instead of using JSON.parse()?

Comment: Thanks @HenryWilliams for quick response. See my updated question Update #1. I don't know how to get the name of the objects (ie Code, Name, EffectDate)

Comment: Since `event.filters` is already an object, you should be able to access its properties directly; `event.filters.Code`, `event.filters.Name`, etc. Not sure if I'm understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: the reason the `split` doesn't work is because you are passing in a **string** ... `this.filters.split(/\b(?:(?!value)\w)+[a-zA-Z0-9/]\b/);` would pass in a regex as you wanted

Comment: `this.data = Object.keys(event.filters).map(key => ({key, value:event.filters[key].value}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like JSON. What's to stop you from just doing `data = JSON.parse(content)` and iterating over the key-values using `keys(data)` for keys and `data[i]["value"]` for values?

Try something like this:

```
var data = [];
for(var i in event.filters){
  data.push({"key": i, "value": event.filters[i].value});
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks @Hong.